# Cartesi Rollups DApp modularity

Tags: blockchain, cartesi

It's been some time that i have a question in my mind. Is it possible to implement a modularity strategy for complex Cartesi Rollups DApps where we have the main logic program (the one responsible for the input loop) depending on one or more HTTP services running separately? The diagram here illustrates the architecture I have in mind.

[image: architecture]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this design will definitely work inside the [Cartesi Machine](https://cartesi.io/en/docs/machine/overview/).

Remember that your dApp is running on a Linux inside the Cartesi Machine. ;-)

That said, you can have these components of your architecture (the HTTP services in your diagram) communicating with each other using whatever protocol that exists in a normal Linux.

Best regards!